# не закрывающийся ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при выборе элемента меню, оно не закрывалось?

Например, меню состоит из чек боксов и я хотел бы выбрать несколько элементов прежде чем закрыть меню:

```xaml
<ContextMenu>
     <MenuItem Header="Check_1" IsCheckable="True"/>
     <MenuItem Header="Check_2" IsCheckable="True"/>
     <MenuItem Header="Check_3" IsCheckable="True"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так

```xaml
<MenuItem StaysOpenOnClick="True">
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405913/menu-subitem-will-not-stay-open-on-click-wpf)